# Namen und Vornamen mit definitem Artikel

Tags: person-names, definite-article

In meiner Schulzeit verwendeten wir unsere Vornamen und Namen immer mit definitem Artikel:

> Der Andreas hat gesagt, dass der Herr Schultz in Deutsch ...

Wie verbreitet ist dieser Sprachgebrauch?

Comment: Wenn ich von meinen Kindern und deren Altersgenossen ausgehe ist dies in der Grundschulzeit durchaus üblich.

Comment: … außerdem im Rheinland bei allen Altersklassen.

Comment: Geht es um räumliche Verbreitung, um soziale Schichten, um Altersgruppen oder um prozentuale Durchdringung?

Answer (score 2):

Nachdem ich sowohl im Nordosten und Südwesten Deutschlands als auch in München gelebt habe, behaupte ich, daß das eine süddeutsche Ausdrucksform ist.
Man findet es in Baden und Bayern, aber selten in Mecklenburg, Brandenburg oder Berlin.