# ''Dies'' oder ''Das''?

Tags: difference

Ich verstehe überhaupt nicht, wann man "dies" anstatt "das" gebrauchen muss. Gibt es villeicht darin irgendwelche Gleichartigkeit mit Englisch, wenn man "this" und "it" gebraucht?

Comment: Related to [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/der-die-das-as-demonstrative-pronouns-intonation-politeness-and-difference-wit)

Comment: Die Möglichkeit, dass man `dies` nie gebrauchen muss (außer man will sagen, dass man `dies` nicht gebrauchen muss) schließt Du aus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use `dies`. You can, if you want to connotate differently than with `das`.

`dies` connotates, that it is very specific, what you are referring to.

`das` connotates, that it is rather generic or general, what you are referring to.

The similarity to English strikes more in the case of

> „dies und das“ = "this and that"

Answer (score 4):

Der Unterschied ist, daß *dies* spezifischer als *das* ist; *das* übersetzt sich zu "the/this/that", während mit *dies* "the/this/that one (in particular)" gemeint ist.

Folgerichtig muß man *dies* anstelle von *das* verwenden, falls ein bestimmtes Objekt zu betonen ist.